# Data passed from view controller returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 view controllers and I pass data from 1 to 2 but the NSString in 2 is empty(null) what am I doing wrong?

**view controller 1 .m**

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"Method 1");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Method 2");
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[allPosts count]);
    return [[[allPosts objectForKey:@"posts"] valueForKey:@"title"] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Method 3");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[allPosts objectForKey:@"posts"] valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OldPostViewController *vc = [[OldPostViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"server/app/post.php?id=%@", [[[allPosts objectForKey:@"posts"] valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    vc.postURL = url;
    NSLog(@"%@", vc.postURL);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewPost" sender:self];
}
```

**view controller 2 .h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OldPostViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *blogView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *postURL;

@end
```

**view controller 2 .m**

```
NSLog(@"URL: %@", _postURL);

NSString *fullURL = _postURL;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[blogView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Please could any one tell me what I could possibly do as I have try all the solutions I could find on Google & Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it like this. When you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` this won't use your locally initialized `vc`.

Implement `prepareForSegue:` for doing this. Like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"viewPost"])
    {
        OldPostViewController *vc= (OldPostViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.postURL = yourURL;
    }
}
```

**Or**

You can do it like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OldPostViewController *vc = [[OldPostViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"server/app/post.php?id=%@", [[[allPosts objectForKey:@"posts"] valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    vc.postURL = url;
    NSLog(@"%@", vc.postURL);
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply, I have implemented the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and everything work except that the view does not show up the screen just goes black what does this mean.

Comment: @user2802926: declare `vc` as a property, instead of local instance then try

Comment: Hi, I instantiated it as a local property and it crashed when trying to present the view controller

Comment: @user2802926: I mean to declare a property like: @property(nonatomic, strong) OldPostViewController *vc; and in your did select initialize it like _vc = [[OldPostViewController alloc] init];

Comment: I tried that didn't work, the url is logged in the console from the second view controller so it is navigating to that view controller class but the screen never show up it is just black?

Comment: @user2802926: I edited my answer can you check now ?

Comment: I have tried it and the breakpoints highlighted this: OldPostViewController *vc = (OldPostViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewPost"];

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the URL in the didSelect method as a property and then access it in prepareSegue method

Sorry I can't write the full code right now :)